# can't clear jtextfield using Documentlistener

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, documentlistener

i have a textfield, when the user inserts a certain number of characters the program should put it in a JTable and clears the textfield, but it fires an event for `Jtextfield.setText("");`

Here's my code:

```
jTextField2.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            printIt();
        }

        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

        }

        private void printIt() {
            //DocumentEvent.EventType type = documentEvent.getType();
            String code=jTextField2.getText().trim();

           // if(type.toString().trim().length()==13)
            if (code.length()==4) {
                   list.add(code);
                   mod.addRow(new Object[]{code});
                   jTextField2.setText(""); 
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To update the text field while using a DocumentListener you need to wrap the code in a SwingUtilities.invokeLater() so the code is executed after all updates have been done to the Document.

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        jTextField2.setText("");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't modify the textfield's doucment inside a DocumentListener. Use a `DocumentFilter` to modify text.

> **Document listeners should not modify the contents of the document**; The
>   change is already complete by the time the listener is notified of the
>   change. Instead, write a custom document that overrides the
>   insertString or remove methods, or both.

In another part.

> You may want to change the document's text within a document listener.
>   However, you should never modify the contents of a text component from
>   within a document listener. If you do, the program will likely
>   deadlock. **Instead, you can use a formatted text field or provide a
>   document filter**.

- All quotes from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html)
- Tutorial [How to write a DocumentFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter)

Comment: then how am i supposed to do it?

Comment: yes sir, but i still need to use a document listener, i'm doing this program for a barcode scanner, so after each read it should clear the textfield.

Comment: hmmm i think i got it somehow i'll read more about it, thanks alot :)